# Jquery select by attribute value not working - incase with space in value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In my checkboxes, i am using select the element using values.. for that (sample) i made like this..

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" value="one 234" />
</form>

function doit(){
    var x = "one 234"
    $(':checkbox[value='+x+']')
    .css({border:"1px solid green"})
}

doit();
```

But is doesn't work.. in case if i remove the space inbetween the value of  "one 234" - it works. how to handle this kind of situation..?

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7sdsm/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use quotes :

```
$(':checkbox[value="'+x+'"]')
```

Or [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), which I personally find cleaner and with which you don't have to worry about any character escaping :

```
$(':checkbox').filter(function(){ return this.value===x })
```